# Calculate month or quarter of a given date for ISOWEEK calendar

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In Excel there is a `ISOWEEK()` function that returns the WEEK of a given date (according to the *ISOWEEK* system). I wonder how to create similar functions for the MONTH and for the QUARTER (i.e. given a certain data, what is its ISO month or its ISO quarter)? Thanks.

I have tried myself to build the functions but by looking at historical data I cant see a regular pattern, for instance depending on the year, some months have 4 or 5 weeks, but this change seems not following a regular pattern. Also the duration of the quarter for the `ISOWEEK` system is not so clear to me, shall I assume that the quarter is always 13  full weeks in the case of years with 52 weeks, and with 13+13+13+14 weeks when the year has 53 weeks?.

There are some functions to calculate the quarter as described here: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2475-excel-convert-date-to-fiscal-year-or-quarter-or-month.html, for instance

Quarter for a given date:

```
=CHOOSE(MONTH(A6),3,3,3,4,4,4,1,1,1,2,2,2)
```

Fiscal month for a given date:

```
=CHOOSE(MONTH(A6),7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

However, seems that they don't completely match the `ISOWEEK` system (for more info about `ISOWEEK`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date ).

`ISOMONTH` should return the given month of a date, for instance `ISOMONTH` (15/01/2019) should return 1. In a similar way, `ISOQUARTER` (15/01/2019) should return 1.

Comment: ISO simply does not define a mapping of ISO weeks to months or quarters, so there's no such thing as an "ISO month" or "ISO quarter" (that would imply the standard defines them, which it doesn't). Per the [WP article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Weeks_per_month) you linked, there are a few such schemes, but they're not ISO.

Comment: Are you looking to return the Gregorian month/quarter? or an ISOMonth/ ISOQuarter?

Comment: Thanks Jeroen and Greg. That is precisely the main difficulty, as the standar does not define it, how do you do if you need to build a "fiscal" calendar dimension table that follows the ISOWEEK standard, in order to define start and end of the fiscal months or quarters (knowing as mentioned that some months have 5 weeks or 4 weeks depending on the year)?

Comment: if I understand it correctly.. you just need to output the month or quarter of a given date .. right? then the 1st "Quarter for a given date" formula & `MONTH()` function should do it just fine. || I'm just curious why the week number is absolutely needed for this purpose...